# Passing Array from a Separate React js file To a Component

Tags: reactjs, arrays

```
const CardData = [
    {
        imgsrc ={require('../../../pictures/yellow.jpg')},
      title = "Hello World",
      details = "Card Details",
    },

]
```

> (method) require(: any): any
> Parsing error: Unexpected token (3:25)eslint

I am getting this error on image tag. I dont know how to pass images in an array like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not a valid syntax, I think you want to try:

```
const CardData = [
  {
    imgsrc: require("../../../pictures/yellow.jpg"),
    title: "Hello World",
    details: "Card Details",
  },
]
```

Comment: Beautiful Dennis... Thank you so much... God Bless you